# What am I missing in trying to pass Variables in an SSIS Execute SQL Task?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am creating an SSIS Execute SQL Task that will use variables but it is giving me an error when I try to use it. When I try to run the below, it gives me an error and when I try to build the query, it gives me an error SQL Sytnax Errors encountered and unable to parse query. I am using an OLEDB connection. Am I not able to use variables to specify the tables?

[image: Select Statement]
[image: Parameters Image]
[image: SQL Syntax Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parameterize a table name.

1. Use the Expressions editor in your Execute SQL Task to Select a SqlStatementSource property.
2. Try `"SELECT * FROM " + @[User::TableName]`
   [image: Selecting Expression]
3. After clicking OK twice (to exit the Task editor), you should be able to reopen the editor and find your table name in the SQL statement.
4. Add a string cast in a case where it might be a simple Object - `(DT_WSTR,100)`

Answer (score -3):

You are using only single parameter(?) in the query and assigning 3 inputs to that parameters which is not fair put only single input and assign some variable as input as shown in image and change the value of variable respectively.[image]

the parameter name should be incremented by 1 start with 0 because they are the indexes representing the "?" in the query which was written the query window.